# C++ Substructure Bitfield Size

Tags: c++, bit-fields

Consider the following:

```
class A { public:
    int     gate_type :  4;
    bool storage_elem :  1;
    uint8_t privilege :  2;
    bool      present :  1;
} __attribute__((packed));

class B { public:
    struct Sub {
        int     gate_type :  4;
        bool storage_elem :  1;
        uint8_t privilege :  2;
        bool      present :  1;
    } type_attr; //Also tried with "__attribute__((packed))" here in addition to outside
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Compiler is g++ 4.8.1.  sizeof(A)==1, sizeof(B)==4.  Why is this so?  I need something like structure B to have size 1.

Comment: FWIW, it looks ok with GCC 4.7.2: http://ideone.com/5UpazC (this is with the attribute applied directly to the inner struct).

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=93e976a41246e1de4cdae7418040122e-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Your code is different from OP's . See http://ideone.com/Z4wOkE

Comment: @johnchen902: I know, but the OP said that he also tried applying the attribute directly to the inner struct.

Comment: Something similar except with unions seems to be the case for the accepted answer here, although there's no explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383708/alignment-of-bitfields-inside-unions?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

This may seem like a dumb counter-question.  I get the result you desire when I rewrite your example as:

```
class A { public:
    int     gate_type :  4;
    bool storage_elem :  1;
    uint8_t privilege :  2;
    bool      present :  1;
} __attribute__((packed));

class B { public:
    A type_attr; //Also tried with "__attribute__((packed))" here in addition to outside
};
```

Is there some reason you can't reuse the definition of `class A` inside of `class B`?  This really seems to be the better way to do it.

As I recall, neither C nor C++ guarantee that `struct Sub` would have identical layout to and have identical storage requirements as `class A`, despite having the same field widths, order and so on.  (In C's case, it'd be `struct Sub` vs. `struct A`, but the same idea holds, since these are all POD types.)

The exact behavior ought to be ABI-dependent.  By reusing `class A` as I did above, though, I think you make yourself slightly more immune to ABI issues.  (Slightly, not impervious.)

Comment: "neither C nor C++ guarantee..." - somewhat irrelevant, as `__attribute__((packed))` is a compiler-specific extension ;)

Comment: This would be an acceptable workaround, +1, although for full points, I'd like to know _why_ my way wasn't working.  Re ABI: it's slightly more complicated--this _is_ in the context of _making_ an OS :-)

Comment: And `__attribute__` is only a non-standard hint to the compiler.  If anything, it should weaken guarantees made by the standard, except when it explicitly makes such guarantees tighter.

In any case, using `class A` directly in `class B` gets the desired effect, at least under the x86-64 ABI.

Comment: @Ian Mallett:  I'll be honest: I'm not sure which ABI detail we're tripping over here.  When I apply `__attribute__((packed))` to both inner and outer `struct` / `class` definitions, `sizeof(B)` returns *2* of all things.  Wild.

Note, in that example I broke the nested  Sub definition away from declaring a class attribute of that type:

class B { public:
    struct Sub {
        int     gate_type :  4;
        bool storage_elem :  1;
        uint8_t privilege :  2;
        bool      present :  1;
    } __attribute((packed))__;
    Sub type_attr;
};